# How can I disconnect social auth from django with social-auth-app-django library using rest API

Tags: python, reactjs, graphql, python-social-auth, social-auth-app-django

I am using two social auth libraries in django framework `social-auth-app-django` and `graphql-social-auth`. I have successfully implemented the login functionality using these libraries but now I want to introduce a feature in my app to disconnect social account. So according to this documentation (https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#disconnection-pipeline) I have added `SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE` but having no idea how can I use this disconnect functionality from my react frontend. I am using React frontend so how can I disconnect social account using rest api?